# Is there a way to run these 2 batch scripts simultaneously? on the same file, combined

Tags: batch-file

I have these 2 scripts .bat working fine individually, but I want to combine them into one, so they can run their commands at the same time, instead of consecutively.

Let me explain my idea:

**I'm testing a program made by a German, which consists of showing bmp images on your cmd console (also using gifs frames on a loop to show animated images as well). the plugin made for this to work is called Insertbmp.exe:**

```
@echo off
title BMP console
cd bin\sprimg
pause
cls

color 0f
mode 81,41
cls
set name=openedk
:loop1
openedk\insertbmp /p:"%name%%loop%.bmp" /x:0 /y:0 /z:0
set /a loop=%loop%+1
if not exist openedk\%name%%loop%.bmp goto endofloop1
timeoutms 100
goto loop1
:endofloop1
set /a lo=%lo%+1
set loop=0
if %lo% lss 4 goto loop1
set lo=0
pause

color f0
mode 62,32
cls
set name=alien
:loop2
alien\insertbmp /p:"%name%%loop%.bmp" /x:0 /y:0 /z:0
set /a loop=%loop%+1
if not exist alien\%name%%loop%.bmp goto endofloop2
timeoutms 100
goto loop2
:endofloop2
set /a lo=%lo%+1
set loop=0
if %lo% lss 4 goto loop2
set lo=0
pause

color 0f
mode 62,22
cls
set name=sleep
:loop3
sleep\insertbmp /p:"%name%%loop%.bmp" /x:0 /y:18 /z:0
set /a loop=%loop%+1
if not exist sleep\%name%%loop%.bmp goto endofloop3
timeoutms 100
goto loop3
:endofloop3
set /a lo=%lo%+1
set loop=0
if %lo% lss 3 goto loop3
set lo=0
pause
color 0f


mode 33,2 
cls
echo End of TEST file
pause
exit
```

**the other one is also a batch script made to type lines by itself, it's called ghost typer:**

```
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=7


set "line1=This was a triumph"
set "line2=I'm making a note here: huge success"
set "line3=It's hard to overstate my satisfaction"
set "line4=Aperture science"
set "line5=We do what we must because we can"
set "line6=For the good of all of us"
set "line7=Except the ones who are dead"

for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :EOF

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,2,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :EOF
set /a num+=1
goto :type
```

Basically, what I have in mind is: run those commands simultaneously on the same line so it doesn't consecutively run them, giving me a cmd console typing whatever I want by it self, while showing me my animated images one by one which I already have on my folder.

on my current situation, it only runs the loop command before it runs the typer codes.

any suggestions?

(I'm rookie on coding anything, sorry)

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. Do you mean the user aGerman on the DosTips.com forums?

Comment: Yep, i recognize that name

Comment: start it in a new process: `start /?`

Comment: the only way is with a new process?

Comment: if you want anything to run in parallel, yes. Batch isn't capable of multithreading, so you need two (independent) processes.